# XMLHttpRequest Synchronous or Asynchronous

Tags: javascript

In my JS I am sending a get request to the bit.ly api to shorted a URL. The problem is I need the URL returned for use in the code.

Would it be best to use a synchronous request for this? As it stands any code after the XHR request that uses the bit.ly would fail because the response has not yet returned the short URL.

```
bitlyXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (bitlyXHR.readyState == 4) {
        if (bitlyXHR.status == 200) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(bitlyXHR.responseText);
            // Do something
        }
    }
};

bitlyXHR.open("GET", "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=&apiKey=&longUrl=" + longURL + "&format=json");
bitlyXHR.send();

// Some code here that uses the short URL
```

Comment: Just put the "Some code here that uses the short URL" instead of the "Do something" code..

Comment: sync ajax is the devil. never use it.

Comment: While it is possible  to use (or to mimic) a syncronous AJAX (XMLHTTPRequest) but it is not the ideal for many reason but the principal is Javascript has a limited process time. So, if the process takes more time to return then Javascript will hang with a message saying that the script is taking too much time (in almost all browser but Iexplorer).

Comment: @Raynos Could you tell me why? I've always seen AJAX-Calls as asynchronous, but recently heard about the sync-calls. What's so bad about them? thanks! *edit* oh, just saw magallanes - comment, so I guess that's the "devil" - part of it :D

Comment: @GNi33 they freeze (or crash for IE9) the entire browser whilst doing the XHR. This means all I can do is stare at a white screen until your doing with the XHR. That makes me rage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function doSomething(obj) {
    // this does something with the result.
}

bitlyXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (bitlyXHR.readyState == 4) {
        if (bitlyXHR.status == 200) {
           var obj = JSON.parse(bitlyXHR.responseText);
           doSomething(obj); 
        }
    }
};

bitlyXHR.open("GET", "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=&apiKey=&longUrl=" + longURL + "&format=json");
bitlyXHR.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that uses the short URL to the section of the code that has the *Do something* comment or, even better, call a function that contains that code from there.

Doing it this way is called *using a callback*.  You supply a function to be executed later when the request returns.  This is the best way to handle an AJAX (the A stands for asynchronous, after all) request as it won't lock up your browser while waiting for the call to complete.